# CSS3 Skew Again! : Unskew text without parent div so form focus state is proper

Tags: forms, css, focus, transform, skew

I have a simple problem, but I may be asking for the impossible.

I want to style my html form elements as parallelograms without skewing the contained text. I would normally do this by applying the transform to a parent div and applying the reverse transform to the content:

http://jsfiddle.net/ExUs9/3/

```
form {
    background:#62CAD9;
    padding:10px;
}
div {
    background: white;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 10px;
    width:300px;
    transform:skewX(30deg);
    -ms-transform:skewX(30deg); 
    -webkit-transform:skewX(30deg);
}
input {
    background: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
    transform:skewX(-30deg);
    -ms-transform:skewX(-30deg); 
    -webkit-transform:skewX(-30deg);
}
```

My problem with the above is the focus property is still applied to the unskewed input box and displays as rectangular. The focus effect is only skewed if the input box itself is skewed:

http://jsfiddle.net/kdqKX/

```
form {
    background:#62CAD9;
}

input {
    margin: 20px;
    background: white;
    width:300px;
    border: none;
    height: 30px;
    transform:skewX(30deg);
    -ms-transform:skewX(30deg); 
    -webkit-transform:skewX(30deg);
}
```

The problem here is that the text is skewed.

I know I could just remove the focus outline, but is there any way to either:

1. Skew the input box--but not the contained text--without skewing via a parent div
2. Apply the border to the parent div when the child input box is focused

I don't know js or any scripts well, so a script free solution is preferred. I do, though, suspect this is impossible in pure css, so let me know any possible solutions.

Thank you, you brave internet geniuses,

Dalton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy solution would be a background image.
CSS gradient can fake this.

```
background-image:linear-gradient(45deg,  #62cad9 0 , #62cad9 2em , transparent 2em ,transparent 230px, #62cad9 230px );
```

Try it without transform. http://jsfiddle.net/khGDj/ 
other easy way, would have been width pseudo-element and borders/blue/transparent. input do not take it as far as i know.

Comment: add more gradient to produce your outline effect.

Comment: That is so cool! Thanks so much G.

If you don't mind, I'm curious to see how to do this with a pseudo element as you mentioned, I tried that approach but couldn't get it working. Even if it won't work with the input, it would still definitely help me with other elements on the site.

Comment: pseudo element would be  ':after {content:'';border:10px solid; border-top:none;border-right:none;}' it makes a 20px high triangle.

Comment: This is a terrific and clever way to do it! Webkit has all sorts of problems (blurry text, z-index etc.) as soon as you transform an element. I need to skew an elements background but not it's inner text and with this I can fake the effect without any skewing/unskewing at all.

Comment: Anyone know if it's possible to skew the input text as well?