# Parallelogram Textbox

Tags: html, css, textbox

How can I create a parallelogram type of textbox where text will be aligned vertically straight.

I'm using CSS below to add skew to my Textbox:

```
#parallelogram {
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(30deg);
       -moz-transform: skew(30deg);
         -o-transform: skew(30deg);
}
```

Textbox alignment was also affected, I just want to make the textbox vertically aligned. (see screenshot below)

[image]

Comment: this question seems similar : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910275/css3-skew-again-unskew-text-without-parent-div-so-form-focus-state-is-proper/ see http://jsfiddle.net/khGDj/1/ (click / focus on input to draw borders)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try giving the skew transform to the parent of your textbox, and removing the border(and outline) of the textbox, so the text that you type has proper vertical alignment.

```
#parallelogram {
    border:1px solid black;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    padding: 0 3px 0 3px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(30deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(30deg);
    -o-transform: skew(30deg);
}
#parallelogram input {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg); //setting the net skew angle to 0
    -moz-transform: skew(-30deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-30deg);
}
```

(`parallelogram` is the id of the div wrapped around the input box)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/p4sRf/)